# Which one is correct -- "transfer here to Khreshchatyk station" or "transfer from here to Khreshchatyk station"?

Tags: grammar

During my everyday commute, I hear a voice announcement stating that the train is approaching a station with a transfer passage:

1. 'Transfer here to Khreshchatyk station.'

However, I have been contemplating whether this phrase is correct. Perhaps it should be voiced as:

2. 'Transfer **from** here to Khreshchatyk station'?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would announce "Transfer here **for** Khreshchatyk".

Comment: You don't say _where_ you are commuting. A common expression in the UK is "Change here for [place name]", meaning that you have to 'change trains' (transfer to another one) at the next station if you want to go to that place.

Answer (score 1):

"Transfer" is an action done at a station. You get off the train you came on and you get on another train at the same station which is going where you want. When you are on the other train your "transfer" is complete.

This means the transfer is done all at one station. It's not *from* one station *to* another (unless you have to get on the train at a different station, which can sometimes happen when there are two stations close together - but that's another story).

So the correct and normal form of the announcement is:

> Transfer here **for** Khreshchatyk station.

That's what you will hear in English-speaking countries (though "change" - a synonym for transfer - is more often used). It means to do the transfer here in order to get to Khreshchatyk station.